# no matching function for call to ‘ros::NodeHandle::advertiseService(const char [12], bool (Eddie::*)(), Eddie* const)’

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I am getting the following error:

```
 **error: no matching function for call to ‘ros::NodeHandle::advertiseService(const char [12], bool (Eddie::*)(), Eddie* const)’**
```

Below is the code:

```
**This is my eddie.cpp class:**
include eddie.h
Eddie::Eddie(){

 
/ get_version_srv is a ros::ServiceServer declared in my .h file
// node_ is a ros::NodeHandle declared in my .h file
  get_version_srv = node_.advertiseService("get_version", &Eddie::get_board_version, this);
  
 node_handle_.param<std::string>("serial_port", port, port);
}
Eddie::~Eddie()

}
  
 
bool Eddie::get_board_version(parallax_eddie_robot::get_version::Request &req, parallax_eddie_robot::get_version::Response &res)

 
/DO STUFF
 
eturn true;

//MAIN FUNCTION

int main(int argc, char** argv)

 
OS_INFO("Initializing the robot's control board");
 
os::init(argc, argv, "parallax_board");
 
ddie eddie;
 
os::Rate loop_rate(10);
 
eturn 0;


*Here is my eddie.h file:**

fndef _EDDIE_H
define _EDDIE_H
include ros/ros.h
include fcntl.h
include termios.h
include semaphore.h
include string
include sstream
include map
class Eddie {
 public:
 Eddie();
 virtual ~Eddie();

private:
 sem_t mutex;
 struct termios tio;
 int tty_fd;
  ros::NodeHandle node_handle_;
  ros::ServiceServer get_version_srv_;
  bool get_board_version(parallax_eddie_robot::get_version::Request &req, parallax_eddie_robot::get_version::Response &res);
};
endif

*With the new changes described in the post below I get the following errors**
**Also modified above code (from original post) to reflect the new changes I have made**
/home/opslab/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/parallax_eddie_robot/include/eddie.h:36:26: error: ‘parallax_eddie_robot’ has not been declared
  /home/opslab/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/parallax_eddie_robot/include/eddie.h:36:69: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘&’ token
 

 /home/opslab/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/parallax_eddie_robot/src/eddie.cpp:7:98: error: no matching function for call to ‘ros::NodeHandle::advertiseService(const char [12], bool (Eddie::*)(int), Eddie* const)’
 /home/opslab/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/parallax_eddie_robot/src/eddie.cpp:7:98: note: candidates are:
 /opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/node_handle.h:821:17: note: template<class T, class MReq, class MRes> ros::ServiceServer ros::NodeHandle::advertiseService(const string&, bool (T::*)(MReq&, MRes&), T*)
 /opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/node_handle.h:859:17: note: template<class T, class MReq, class MRes> ros::ServiceServer ros::NodeHandle::advertiseService(const string&, bool (T::*)(ros::ServiceEvent<MReq, MRes>&), T*)
 /opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/node_handle.h:898:17: note: template<class T, class MReq, class MRes> ros::ServiceServer ros::NodeHandle::advertiseService(const string&, bool (T::*)(MReq&, MRes&), const boost::shared_ptr<X>&)
 /opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/node_handle.h:938:17: note: template<class T, class MReq, class MRes> ros::ServiceServer ros::NodeHandle::advertiseService(const string&, bool (T::*)(ros::ServiceEvent<MReq, MRes>&), const boost::shared_ptr<X>&)
 /opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/node_handle.h:975:17: note: template<class MReq, class MRes> ros::ServiceServer ros::NodeHandle::advertiseService(const string&, bool (*)(MReq&, MRes&))
 /opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/node_handle.h:1011:17: note: template<class MReq, class MRes> ros::ServiceServer ros::NodeHandle::advertiseService(const string&, bool (*)(ros::ServiceEvent<MReq, MRes>&))
 /opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/node_handle.h:1045:17: note: template<class MReq, class MRes> ros::ServiceServer ros::NodeHandle::advertiseService(const string&, const boost::function<bool(MReq&, MRes&)>&, const VoidConstPtr&)
 /opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/node_handle.h:1083:17: note: template<class S> ros::ServiceServer ros::NodeHandle::advertiseService(const string&, const boost::function<bool(S&)>&, const VoidConstPtr&)
 /opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/node_handle.h:1111:17: note: ros::ServiceServer ros::NodeHandle::advertiseService(ros::AdvertiseServiceOptions&)
 /opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/node_handle.h:1111:17: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 3 provided
 
home/opslab/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/parallax_eddie_robot/src/eddie.cpp: At global scope:
 /home/opslab/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/parallax_eddie_robot/src/eddie.cpp:86:31: error: ‘bool Eddie::get_board_version’ is not a static member of ‘class Eddie’
  /home/opslab/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/parallax_eddie_robot/src/eddie.cpp:86:31: error: ‘parallax_eddie_robot’ has not been declared
  /home/opslab/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/parallax_eddie_robot/src/eddie.cpp:86:75: error: ‘req’ was not declared in this scope
  /home/opslab/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/parallax_eddie_robot/src/eddie.cpp:86:80: error: ‘parallax_eddie_robot’ has not been declared
  /home/opslab/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/parallax_eddie_robot/src/eddie.cpp:86:125: error: ‘res’ was not declared in this scope
  /home/opslab/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/parallax_eddie_robot/src/eddie.cpp:86:128: error: expression list treated as compound expression in initializer [-fpermissive]
  /home/opslab/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/parallax_eddie_robot/src/eddie.cpp:87:1: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48780/no-matching-function-for-call-to-%E2%80%98ros::nodehandle::advertiseservice(const-char-%5B12%5D,-bool-(eddie::*)(),-eddie*-const)%E2%80%99/) by [kbedolla](https://answers.ros.org/users/3639/kbedolla/) on ROS Answers with karma: 48 on 2012-11-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kbedolla](https://answers.ros.org/users/3639/kbedolla/) on 2012-11-21**:
I made the necessary changes and made my get_board_version function take in the necessary parameters so the function signature looks like the following: bool get_board_version(parallax_eddie_robot::get_version::Request &req, parallax_eddie_robot::get_version::Response &res);

**Comment by [kbedolla](https://answers.ros.org/users/3639/kbedolla/) on 2012-11-21**:
However, I still get the same error along with new errors: I will put the list of errors above by editing the original post.

**Comment by [kbedolla](https://answers.ros.org/users/3639/kbedolla/) on 2012-11-22**:
Thanks petermilani. However, I am still getting the "‘parallax_eddie_robot’ has not been declared" error. As well as "error: ‘bool Eddie::get_board_version’ is not a static member of ‘class Eddie'". Also an error saying that my parameters for the get_version_function 'was not declared in this scope'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Fixed it! Long story short, I forgot to include the header for my service in my header file. Thanks for everyone's answers!

---

Originally posted by [kbedolla](https://answers.ros.org/users/3639/kbedolla/) with karma: 48 on 2012-11-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well your error message seems pretty clear: it simply says that you cannot call advertiseService with those parameters.
In particular you are passing function `Eddie::get_board_version`, which accept no parameters, while the definition of `advertiseService` expects a function defined as    `bool(*)(ServiceEvent< MReq, MRes > &)`.

Check the [documentation](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1NodeHandle.html#a08d45aeff99749f76c29ec973bc943a8) of `ros::NodeHandle`.

---

Originally posted by [Saphrosit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2516/saphrosit/) with karma: 197 on 2012-11-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you cant intialise a ServiceServer in your header file as it isn't really called in your main code. Your function to be called can be in your header file, but try moving your

get_version_srv = node_.advertiseService("get_version", &Eddie::get_board_version, this);

plus any referencing of your node (it probably cant be declared in a header file) into your main code, and instead of using "this" as the last parameter, you need  &eddie.

I had this same problem and it was do to an incorrect value in the third parameter.

so that your main code is:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    ROS_INFO("Initializing the robot's control board");
    ros::init(argc, argv, "parallax_board");
    Eddie eddie;
    //plus initialisation of _node
    get_version_srv = node_.advertiseService("get_version", &Eddie::get_board_version, &eddie);
    ros::Rate loop_rate(10);
    return 0;
}
```

---

Originally posted by [PeterMilani](https://answers.ros.org/users/3621/petermilani/) with karma: 1493 on 2012-11-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3